# How to get Mapnik running on Win?

Tags: mapnik

I have installed Mapnik-2.0.1rc0 in windows 7 32bit machine. I then tested the installation by `import mapnik from *` and it did not return any error. But when I tried to input the config version checking by `mapnik-config -v`, it returns a name error. When I tried to run `rundemo.py`, the following error occurred:

> the mapnik library and python bindings must have been compiled and installed successfully before running this script

This probably happened due to improperly set `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH`.

**How to add PythonPath?**

Thanks

Comment: shouldn't it be `mapnik-config -v` instead of `manik-config -v`; and `rundemo.py` instead of `ruundemo.py`?

Comment: Sorry for that. it will be mapnik-config -v and rundemo.py

Answer (score 2):

Explanation exist on Github project [Manual instructions for install Mapnik on Windows](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/WindowsInstallation#manual-instructions).

Step 3 is for you ;-)

Comment: this should be marked as answer